# How can I draw my own string array with a Rust fltk table example?

Tags: rust

Please! forgive my English writing skill!...

I confirm `sarray` value changed through my `mycallback1` routine. (another function...)
however `table.draw_cell` is not!.

How can i draw my string array and string array be changed through my function!

```rust
//..omitted

fn mycallback1(sarray : &mut [&str]) {
    let max = 200 * 11;
    for n in 0..max {
        sarray[n] = "Array ^^^";
    }
}


fn main() { 
    //..omitted;

    let mut sarray = [""; 200 * 11];
    let max = 200 * 11;
    for n in 0..max {
        sarray[n] = "array ^";
    }

    butStock1.set_callback(Box::new(move || mycallback1(&mut sarray)));

    // Called when the table is drawn then when it's redrawn due to events

    table.draw_cell(Box::new(move |ctx, row, col, x, y, w, h| match ctx {
        table::TableContext::StartPage => draw::set_font(Font::Helvetica, 14),
        table::TableContext::ColHeader => {
            let idx = col as usize;
            draw_header(&format!("{}", tuple[idx]), x, y, w, h);
        } // Column titles
        table::TableContext::RowHeader => draw_header(&format!("{}", row + 1), x, y, w, h), // Row titles
        table::TableContext::Cell => {
            let idx = (row * 11 + col) as usize;
            println!("Drawn {}", idx);
            draw_data( &format!("{} {}", sarray[idx], idx), x, y, w, h, table_c.is_selected(row, col),); // Data in cells
        }
        _ => (),
    }));
    app.run().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Example screen shot like! https://imgur.com/q10vN3n

Answer (score 0):

The way fltk works is that it only redraws a widget when a "damage" flag is set, for example when a button is clicked, the click sets a damage flag within the button class, so fltk would redraw it in the next frame.

A table is also redrawn when it's "damaged". Changing the value in the array, fltk has no way of knowing that it has to redraw the table.

So you can add an explicit redraw call, either of the table, or of the whole app.

```
butStock1.set_callback(Box::new(move || {
    mycallback1(&mut sarray);
    fltk::app::redraw();
}));
```

Comment: Works fine!, however  sarray value doesn't change anyway!.